# yarn - What does @npm mean?

Tags: material-ui, yarnpkg

I know that running `yarn add package@1.2.3` would install `package v1.2.3`.

I recently encountered this syntax: `yarn add package@npm`. What does `@npm` do? Is it a special sign for yarn or is it specific to that package (`material-ui`)?

*I encountered `@npm` as a solution to include two versions of material-ui by aliasing the next version: `yarn add material-ui-next@npm:material-ui@next`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real surprises, it is a directive to install a specific package from npm.

`yarn add {package1}` installs the specified package from the npm registry by default.

`yarn add {package1}@npm:{package2}` installs *package2* from the npm registry and assigns *package1* as its alias.

It makes no difference if a package named *package1* exists in the npm registry, it will only download the package you've specified with the *@npm* directive.

From your question, it seems like you've already got a handle on this one.

Comment: But couldn't I just use `yarn add {package1}:{package2}`? If so, what's the difference between that syntax and the syntax with `@npm`?